# Bootstrap style grid using flexbox

Tags: css

I am trying to create a 6 column grid using just flexbox just like bootstrap but when I give width it does not wrap. Any idea, what I could be doing wrong?

When I provide the width to the outer body it does not want to wrap. I am so confuse on what I am doing. Could someone explain me how bootstrap is making their grid using flexbox. I try to inspect and follow what they were doing but not able to create it

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flex-container > .outerbody {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="outerbody">
  <p class="title">Done</p>
  <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
  <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
</div>

<div class="outerbody">
  <p class="title">Done</p>
  <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
  <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
</div>
<div class="outerbody">
  <p class="title">Done</p>
  <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
  <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
</div>
<div class="outerbody">
  <p class="title">Done</p>
  <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
  <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
</div>
<div class="outerbody">
  <p class="title">Done</p>
  <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
  <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
</div>
<div class="outerbody">
  <p class="title">Done</p>
  <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
  <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: your link is wrong ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ppatel08/pen/OJyajpp

Yes I am so sorry. I am trying to format it but looks like it does not want to format

Comment: Viewing your code a full screen version it is wrapping. Just the last two. Were you hoping to keep those the same width as the top??

Comment: Yes and I want to start the next grid from left and not from the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you give each individual width, it adjusts itself according to the screen width and scrolls down the areas that overflow from the screen. If you don't give width, each one sets its own size as much as its content and takes up space on the screen accordingly. Same logic as the column logic in Bootstrap.

I don't understand exactly what you were asking. I can be of more help if you state that I want such a structure.

If you want all divs to be sorted in the same width, you have to remove the flex property.

```
.flex-container > .outerbody {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

updated:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flex-container > .outerbody {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This is very close. But rather then going one by one down it takes two at a time down. I will also upload image to what exactly I need. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Basically all I am trying to do is create the grid where each div will go down one by one down rather then two div going down on resize. Also it leaves the lot of white space on right hand side

Comment: maybe you can change *width: 400px * or something, for this. Whatever width you give them, they'll align themselves because

Comment: ı updated to my answer. I suppose you want this to happen ? now they'll all go down from the starting point to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Add `max-width: 300px;` to class `.flex-container > .outerbody` if you want the last two to have the same width.

Remove `justify-content: space-around;` if you do not need to display the flex items with space before, between, and after the lines

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flex-container>.outerbody {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="outerbody">
    <p class="title">Done</p>
    <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
    <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
  </div>

  <div class="outerbody">
    <p class="title">Done</p>
    <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
    <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
  </div>
  <div class="outerbody">
    <p class="title">Done</p>
    <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
    <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
  </div>
  <div class="outerbody">
    <p class="title">Done</p>
    <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
    <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
  </div>
  <div class="outerbody">
    <p class="title">Done</p>
    <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
    <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
  </div>
  <div class="outerbody">
    <p class="title">Done</p>
    <p class="description">Add eggs & breads for preferably breakfast</p>
    <button class="btn">Mark as done</button>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hello @yinsweet Thank you for the answer what this does it still bring two down rather then one column down when resizing window

Comment: Hi @danny What do you mean bring two down rather than one column? It will wrap according to the width of your viewport. I can see 5 columns in a row at a viewport size of 1920px. You may check your viewport size at https://www.mydevice.io/

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you want a 6 columns grid layout simply change your css to this:

```
.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  flex-flow: wrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flex-container > .outerbody {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: although this seems to be a very easy solution this will not work on IE.